# Adding an extra line with less points using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add an extra line which contains less points.
I have tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=c(1:50),y=c(1:50)*2+5)
df2 <-  data.frame(x=c(20,30,40),y=c(40,60,80))
plot1 <- ggplot(df , aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line()
plot2 <- plot1+ geom_line( aes(x=df2$x, y=df2$y))
plot2
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass `df2` to the `data` argument of the second `geom_line` call and change the mapping slightly

```
plot2 <- plot1+ geom_line( aes(x=x, y=y), data = df2)
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much. That was very helpful.